# NodeJs: I cant call http api without https

Tags: node.js, rest, http, https

I triying to connect to a http api (not https) and all the libraries that i test (https, request, axios, SuperAgent and Got) only work with https.
The error that I get is:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL]: Protocol "http:" not supported. Expected "https:"
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:152:11)
    at request (https.js:314:10)
(...)
```

The code:

```
  const https = require('https');

  https
    .get('http://ip-api.com/json/24.48.0.1', resp => {
      let data = '';

      // A chunk of data has been recieved.
      resp.on('data', chunk => {
        data += chunk;
      });

      // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
      resp.on('end', () => {
        console.log(JSON.parse(data).explanation);
      });
    })
    .on('error', err => {
      console.log('Error: ' + err.message);
    });
```

Who I can connect with http?

Thanks

Comment: Seeing errors is nice and all, but seeing the code that causes it would be preferred. Also, is the api you are accessing yours or a third-party? If not yours, what api is it?

Comment: @JDunken I added the code in the post, the API is from ip-api.com. That doesnt got https in free mode.

Comment: You are literally using `const https = require('https');` and wondering why it's using https? Change it to `require('http')` The error is because you are passing a `http` request to a `https` handler.